# Extract numeric from string into new columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-manipulation, dml

I'm trying to create a new column (y) from another column (x) - my aim is to extract the numeric value after the 1st space of the string from the right-hand side, and if there is no numeric value after the space, then NULL.
I used the following SQL query below; however, the query extracted both numeric and non-numeric after the space into the new column (y) - please see the first image below. I have also attempted to use case statement but have yet to achieve the required output.

```
SELECT x, SUBSTR(x, INSTR(x,' ', -1) + 1) AS y
    FROM  <table_name>;
```

[image: Return table from above query]

I would like the table to return:-

[image: Correct table display]

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try regular expression function `REGEXP_SUBSTR`

```
SELECT x, REGEXP_SUBSTR (x, '(\s)(\d+)$') AS y
FROM <table_name>
```

Please check demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7bc0ee/4866

Comment: what does '(\s)(\d+)$' mean? Also if there is a number I want to retrieve from the left-hand side of the first space how would I change '(\s)(\d+)$'?

Comment: It means group of digit characters ('\d') at the end ('$') of string, seperated by space ('/s').  If you need to retrieve group of numbers from the start of string, you could use pattern '^(\d+)(\s)'

Comment: You could find out more about regular expression here https://regexone.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your `SUBSTRING` idea, you can use `VALIDATE_CONVERSION` to check whether your substring is numeric or not.

Then a `CASE` will select this substring or `NULL` if not numeric:

```
SELECT x, 
CASE WHEN VALIDATE_CONVERSION(SUBSTR(x, INSTR(x,' ', -1) + 1) AS NUMBER) = 1
  THEN SUBSTR(x, INSTR(x,' ', -1) + 1)
  ELSE NULL END AS y
FROM yourtable;
```

Try out [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WQ6MpPxg)

Here the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD) of `VALIDATE_CONVERSION`